# Javascript variable scope issue - probably simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I am looking for a quick solution to this issue:

```
function remove() {
    var clickedbtn;
    $("button[role=remove]").click(function() {
        clickedbtn = this.id;
        alert(clickedbtn); // works, assigns correct value
    });
    alert(clickedbtn); // undefined -- why?
}
```

The clicked variable is declared with var and assigned a value but the value isn't persistent outside the click() function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect to find out which button the user clicked before the click happens?

Comment: How could it *possibly* work if assigning to `clickedbtn` (and never to `clicked`)? Now, even fixing that such that it reads `clicked = this.id`, it will still display "undefined" because the alert happens **before** the user had a chance to click the button.

Comment: your function is incorrect, nothing assign for `clicked`.

Comment: Just a tip: don't but simple or help in the title. It bloats the title with unnecessary words and doesn't help people searching afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use the variable in the outer function, the `click()` hasn't run yet, since the user didn't click yet.

You cannot predict what the value will be in the future.

---

Separately from that issue, your variable names don't match.  (`clicked` isn't `clickedbtn`)

Comment: He's right. That is the point I brought up in my update. clicked is never being assigned anything. The OP is just alerting the id. Not assigning anything to clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**You're never assigning a value toclicked!**

so

```
function remove() {
    var clicked;
    $("button[role=remove]").click(function() {
        clickedbtn = this.id;
        alert(clickedbtn);
        clicked = true; // or if you want clicked set to the id of the button then clicked = this.id;
    });
    alert(clicked);
}
```

Comment: That will not make any difference.

Comment: @SLaks you're right. I saw he's never assigning anything to clicked and updated my answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with scopes - it has to do with *when* code is run. Asynchronous code is asynchronous and this problem is the same as [incorrectly assigning a variable in an AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Take the following code (where I have corrected the assignment to the non-existent "clickedbtn" variable) which indicates *when* things will run by per the numbers in the comments:

```
# 1
var clicked = "initial value";
# 2
$("button[role=remove]").click(function() {
    # At some point -AFTER- 3
    clicked = this.id;
    alert(clicked);
});
# 3
alert(clicked);
```

This is because the click callback is only called **after** the user clicks the button (read: "at some point in the future") while the `.click` function to add the callback handler returns *immediately* and the following code to display the alert is executed *immediately* which happens *before* the variable has been assigned the ID of the element which may be clicked *in the future*.